# Edit Comment jumping to bottom of page when filter applied

Tags: excel

I have a table which one column is full of comments. There are multiple rows added and deleted each day.

Each Comment is set to "do not move or size with cells" so when I click view comment it appears next to the box which is great. This seems to be worse when I have a filter applied to the table.

However, if I click Edit Comment it jumps down the page, way after the actual bottom of the sheet. I actually tried all three of the options in Format Comment and it doesn't change.

I have Page Breaks on which hasn't helped.

I've searched and searched online and I can't find anything that relates to the edit comment jumping.